# How to merge nil cases to Failing case

Tags: swift, rx-swift

```
import MVVMC
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import RTVModel
import RTVWebAPI

public class SettingsViewModel: ViewModel {

    public var fetchedNotifications: Driver<[NotificationItem]> = .empty()

    public var fetchedNotificationsFailed: Driver<String> = .empty()

    public var notificationCount: Driver<Int> = .empty()
'''''''''''''''
    public var userLoginName: Driver<String> = .empty()
///// userLoginName getting is a optional String.

'''''''''''''''''

    public var fetchedUserLoginNameFailed: Driver<String> = .empty()

    public func bindNotificationEvents(with trigger: Driver<Void>) {

        let webService: Driver<RTVInformationListWebService> = trigger
            .map { RTVInformationListParameters() }
            .webService()

        let result = webService.request()

        notificationCount = result.success().map { $0.informationList.maxCount }
        fetchedNotifications = result.success()
            .map {$0.informationList.notifications}
------->    .map {$0.map {NotificationItem.init(notification: $0)}}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Error (Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String')
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        fetchedNotificationsFailed = Driver.merge(fetchedNotificationsFailed, result.error().map { $0.message })
    }

    public func bindUserInfoEvents(with trigger: Driver<Void>) {

        let webService: Driver<RTVMobileMenuWebService> = trigger
            .map { RTVMobileMenuParameters() }
            .webService()

        let result = webService.request()
        userLoginName = result.success().map { ($0.mobileMenuInfo.username) }
        fetchedUserLoginNameFailed = Driver.merge(fetchedUserLoginNameFailed, result.error().map { $0.message })

    }
}

    extension RTVAPIError {
        fileprivate var message: String {
            var message = "\(self.localizedDescription)"
            if let codeNumber = self.codeNumber {
                message += "\n(\(codeNumber))"
            }
            return message
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to merge the nil case to  fetchUserLoginNameFailed Driver

Answer (score 1):

This is not really the way you should be using it, since the point of `Driver` is not to error, but you obviously have an error state, therefore, `Observable` or `Signal` would be better.

However, you need to split your signal into successful ones and error ones, something like this:

```
fetchedNotifications = result.success()
    .map {$0.informationList.notifications}
    .share(replay: 1)

let success = fetchedNotifications
    .filter { $0 != nil }
    .map { $0.map { NotificationItem.init(notification: $0) } }

let error = fetchedNotifications
    .filter { $0 == nil } // Here would be your "error" state which you can merge later
```

I might be off with the syntax, I wrote this from memory.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using the catchOnNil
    .catchOnNil { return  }